# How to insert a vector object from R into PostgreSQL column of type double precision [], which a float array

Tags: arrays, r, postgresql, list, vector

The data fcast_load_vector is a 1440 length float vector in R.
It is uploaded in PostgreSQL , into the column fcast_load which houses datatype double precision[]. I am trying to insert data from R into PostgreSQL. But, My RStudio session is aborted whenever I run the following command.

Executing the code on R 3.6 on my linux machine gives the error : *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R terminated

ERROR: RS-DBI Driver, could not retrieve the result: Error: malformed array literals list(forecast -> c(4.05,...

I can't find any solution to the above.

```
fcast_type_id = 0 
fcast_no = 190126 # (date in int (%y%m%d format)

con = dbConnect(pg, dbname= db_name, user= user_name host=host_ip password=pwd)
query = 'INSERT INTO data_analytics.test_gs_output(fcast_type_id,fcast_no, fcast_date, fcast_load) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)'
dtab = dbExecute(con, query,list(fcast_type_id,fcast_no,fcast_date,fcast_load_vector))
```

Comment: can your provide a sample of your data `fcast_type_id`, `fcast_no` etc , please?

Comment: added in the question. Edited